# Number pyramid,beginner recursion tracking difficulty?

Tags: java, recursion

I am a beginner in JAVA, and I am having some difficulties tracking recursion and understaning it fully and so here I have the code for a program that if we write 3, it will output:

1
12
123
12
1

Or if we write 5, it will output

1
12
123
1234
12345
1234
123
12
1

```
public class Aufgabe3 {

    private static void printSequenz(int n) {
        if(n<1) {
            return;
        }   
        printLoToHi(n-1);
        printMany(n);
        printHiToLo(n-1);
    }

    private static void printHiToLo(int n){
        if(n<1){
            return;
        }
        printMany(n);
        printHiToLo(n-1);
    }

    private static void printLoToHi(int n){
        if(n<1){
            return;
        }
        printLoToHi(n-1);
        printMany(n);
    }

    private static void printMany(int n){
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSequenz(5);
    }
}
```

Now here is what I don't understand. For example at the method printHiToLo it calls the method printMany(n), and then it calls itself for n-1, and this repeats until n is greater than 0. But I don't understand how the method printLoToHi works? How does it ever reach the printMany method? If it just calls itself until n is greater than 0. This is really confusing to me... Thanks to anyone that helps me out :)

Comment: You should really include a link to your earlier question here, so that nobody duplicates barak manos' explanations there when they answer this one.

Comment: Sorry, I din't know that, because I am new in this whole community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void printLoToHi(int n){
        if(n<1){          // This is the base case that terminates the recursion.
            return;       // You'll always have one - sometimes more.
        }
        printLoToHi(n-1); // This is where the recursion takes place.
        printMany(n);     // But when n < 1 it returns to here and continues on.
}
```

So you see it does indeed get called; only after the base case (n < 1) is reached.

An easy example would be if you called it with `printLoToHi(1)`...

1. It will pass the `if` condition.
2. It calls itself with `n - 1` (0) as an argument.
3. This time it fails the condition and returns.
4. `n == 1` in our original method.
5. `printMany(1)` is called.

Comment: Aha. I thought that when it reaches return, it terminates the whole method, but if I understand this correctly, when it reaches the return, it goes continues the code below the recursive method, for each argument that we passed, for example in this case that would be 1 and then 2, 3, 4 and so on.. right? Btw thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: Ohhh sorry, I thought that I could give you both a green tick. Sorry mate, I also had no idea who posted it first, and I also liked your answer more, hence I asked you the question....

Comment: This is my first day at this website, please understand that I don't know how it fully functions....

Comment: @BetimNeutron, thanks. No, you had it right to begin with. *That* function does terminate when you reach the return statement. But it's returning to the function that called it. This is seen in my steps 3-5. It returns and the `n` is the value it was when *that* method called the recursive function. I would recommend to set breakpoints on `printMany` and the `return` statement and watch what happens in a debugger for a small/known integer like 1 in my example.

Comment: @BetimNeutron, it's all good, I appreciate the change. BTW, welcome. I'm going to erase the commentary about the "green tick" :) Also, if you want to show appreciation for multiple answers, you can vote them up.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. Just one more thing, and I will try to solve this in you way for n=3.
1.It will pass the if condition.
2.It calls itself with n - 1 (2) as an argument.
This time it fails the condition and returns.
n == 1 in our original method.
printMany(1) is called.

Comment: @BetimNeutron, Nope. You will continue to count down until `n` is actually `< 1`. The `if` condition isn't tricky. It's saying - if (this is true) { "I do this" }. So, when it's (2), you'll call it again, and again one more time. Now you will begin to unwind the stack of calls you've made.

Comment: I still can't vote, because I wanted to give an upvote, but I need to have a 15 reputation. Anyway I fully understood your example, but if n was for example bigger than one, than it continues the code from the recursive method down for each n that we had.. right?

Answer (score -1):

Look, your functions are executed line by line. So in `printLoToHi` recursive call is executed and then `printMany` is called.

For example how works `printLoToHi(3)`:
It checks if 3 less than 1. Then calls `printLoToHi(2)`.
It checks if 2 is less than 1. Then calls `printLoToHi(1)`.
It checks if 1 is less than 1. Then calls `printLoToHi(0)`.
It checks if 0 is less than 1. It is, so it returns.
Then `printMany(1)` is called.
Then `printMany(2)` is called.
Then `printMany(3)` is called.

You can consider a recursive call as a single function which does something and don't think how it works. You can assume it works and write other part of function. If that part is correct - the recursion is correct.